# express session store user agent

Tags: node.js, session, express, web-crawler

I set up session management in my node js/ express js website successfully. I stores session data in mongo db. I want the session to be valid for the users who log in for a couple of weeks. The code is as follows:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({ mongoose_connection: db }),
    secret: 'cookie_secret',
    cookie: { maxAge: null }
}));
```

It works fine for normal users, but my problem is with web crawlers such as google bots and facebook bots. I still want them to crawl my website but I don't want their sessions to be stored in my mongo db. It's taking up lots of space and storage is increasing daily which costs me money.

How to selectively choose which sessions to be stored in the db. I can check for `req.headers['user-agent']`, but where to use it in my code? How to tell express-session not to store session sometimes?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the session middleware conditionally, based on the `User-Agent` header. A simple example:

```
var sessionMiddleware = require('express-session')({
  ...configuration here...
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var ua = req.get('user-agent');
  // If the User-Agent header contains the string "Googlebot",
  // skip the session middleware.
  if (/Googlebot/.test(ua)) {
    req.session = {}; // perhaps a bit too simple?
    return next();
  }
  return sessionMiddleware(req, res, next);
});
```

It would depend on your actual use of `req.session` if the code above works, or if you need to mock `req.session` a bit better (for instance, if you use any of the `req.session` methods in your code,
you may need to mock those too).

Comment: That's a pretty clever way to handle the issue, goes right in my snippets. May I suggest setting the TTL to 60sec so the session is usable, but disappears fast?

Comment: @xShirase I'm not sure if that's possible. TTL is set in the configuration of `express-session`, so is system-wide. I don't think you can override it for one particular session (in a useful way).